# Best way to parallelize thousands of downloads

Tags: java, multithreading, java-stream, completable-future, fileutils

I am creating an application in which I have to download thousands of images (~1 MB each) using Java.

I take a list of Album URLs in my REST request, each Album contains multiple number of images.

So my request looks something like:

```
[
  "www.abc.xyz/album1",
  "www.abc.xyz/album2",
  "www.abc.xyz/album3",
  "www.abc.xyz/album4",
  "www.abc.xyz/album5"
]
```

Suppose each of these albums have 1000 images, so I need to download 50000 images in parallel.

Right now I have implemented it using `parallelStream()` but I feel that I can optimize it further.

There are two principle classes - `AlbumDownloader` and `ImageDownloader` (Spring components).

So the main application creates a `parallelStream()` on the list of albums:

```
albumData.parallelStream().forEach(ad -> albumDownloader.downloadAlbum(ad));
```

And a parallelStream() inside AlbumDownloader -> downloadAlbum() method as well:

```
List<Boolean> downloadStatus = albumData.getImageDownloadData().parallelStream().map(idd -> imageDownloader.downloadImage(idd)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I am thinking about using `CompletableFuture` with `ExecutorService` but I am not sure what pool size should I use?

Should I create a separate pool for each Album?

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Math.min(albumData.getImageDownloadData().size(), 1000));
```

That would create 5 different pools of 1000 threads each, that'll be like 5000 threads which might degrade the performance instead of improving.

Could you please give me some ideas to make it very very fast ?

I am using Apache Commons IO `FileUtils` to download files by the way and I have a machine with 12 available CPU cores.

Comment: Have you considered profiling? Because there is no such magic number.

Comment: The upper limit will be determined by the response time of the image server and the download bandwidth of your internet connection.  Java's NIO has asynchronous stuff that should spare you threads, but I think you can savely afford as may threads as necessary to completely exhaust the server capacity or the bandwith.

Comment: I think that the better way is to parallelize only albums not images, and if they are too many, use pagination. In addition what will be faster, getting 1000 images in parallel or in stack?

Comment: @JohnyDeph - I want to download the images in parallel as well. Consider a scenario where I pass just one album containing 5000 images. I don't want those 5000 images to be downloaded sequentially right? Each image download is a combination of a new connection to the server (with the exact image URL) plus the process to save that image into the disk.

Comment: I don't see any problem here, even if 10000 images will be in one thread. Ok 10000 threads with 10000 connections with parallel behaviour. First question: What will be with your source of data if there are will be multiple devices with the same parallel behaviour? Second question: What if your internet connection is too slow? Your parallelize became useless, right?  Third question: Connection to database, you should create new connection for each thread, you think it's ok? Sorry, if I'm wrong

Comment: @JohnyDeph, here are the answers to your questions:

1. There are no multiple devices. It is going to be a small utility application hosted on a single machine.

2. Internet connection is assumed to be pretty fast. So no concerns on this front.

3. There is no connection to any databases.

Comment: Oh, ok! It's up to you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Suppose each of these albums have 1000 images, so I need to download 50000 images in parallel.

It's wrong to think of your application doing 50000 things in parallel.  What you are trying to do is to optimize your throughput – you are trying to download all of the images in the shortest amount of time.

You should try one fixed-sized thread-pool and then play around with the number of threads in the pool until your optimize your throughput – maybe start with double the number of processors.  If your application is mostly waiting for network or the server then maybe you can increase the number of threads in the pool but you wouldn't want to overload the server so that it slows to a crawl and you wouldn't want to thrash your application with a huge number of threads.

> That would create 5 different pools of 1000 threads each, that'll be like 5000 threads which might degrade the performance instead of improving.

I see no point in multiple pools unless there are different servers for each album or some other reason why the downloads from each album are different.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to make it "very very fast" is to get a "very very fast" network connection to the server; e.g. co-locate your client with the server that you are downloading from.

Your download speeds are going to be constrained by a number of potential bottlenecks.  These include:

1. The performance of the server; i.e. how fast it can assemble the data to send to you and push it through its network interface.
2. Per-user request limits imposed by the service.
3. The end-to-end performance of the network path between your client and the server.
4. The performance of the machine you are running on in terms of moving data from the network and putting it (I guess) onto your local disk.

The bottleneck could be any of these, or a combination of them.

Throwing thousands of threads at the problem is unlikely to improve things.  Indeed, if anything it is likely to make performance less than optimal.  For example:

- it could congest your network link, or
- it could trigger anti-hogging or anti-DOS defenses in the server you are fetching from.

A better (simple) idea would be to use an ExecutorService with a *small* bounded worker pool, and submit the downloads to the pool as tasks.

Other things:

1. Try to keep HTTP / HTTPS connections open between downloads from the same server.  Some client libraries will do this kind of thing for you.
2. If you have to download from a number of different servers, try to balance the load across the servers.  Consider implementing per-server queues and trying to balance work so that individual servers don't see "bursts" of activity.

---

I would also advise you to make sure that you have **permission** to do what you are doing.  Companies in the music publishing business have good lawyers.  They could make your life unpleasant<sup>1</sup> if they perceive you to be violating their terms and conditions or stealing their intellectual property.

<sup>1 - Like blocking your IP address or issuing take-down requests to your service provider.</sup>